# Comfort vs comfort

Tags: frames

New to the sport of cycling and considering two bikes. The Domane trek 4.3 Disc 2015 and the Domane 4.3 trek 2014 . It's for a 120 km event. Which would give more body comfort in such a distance ? I've had lower back , shoulder & hamstring issues . Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You're gonna try to do 120km right off the bat? If you really are new to cycling, you need to start with waaaay smaller distances. Like 30km or less. Also, unless you're flushed with ca$h, you shouldn't buy a $2k bike straight off.

Comment: Also, whatever you buy, especially since you've "...had lower back , shoulder & hamstring issues..." you **definitely** need to have a professional bike fit done.

Comment: But they are the same bike - one disc and one not.  They are going to have the same ride/comfort.   Product recommendations are frowned upon here.

Comment: Or nearly the same bike. The fork might be different, and its not clear that the non-disc version is disc ready.

Comment: Theoretically the disc version will be slightly stiffer when it comes to vibrations, as the fork and stays have to slightly thicker to deal with the disc brake mounts. In reality that will make little difference, the biggest difference will be in fit, saddle, and bar/bartape.

Comment: Lower back pain is exaggerated by a leaning-forward position, for me.  So you want a relatively upright position, and good pants.

Answer (score 1):

They are probably going to feel the same, as it's the same bike.  Depending on how hilly you're ride is the only real difference you might feel in comfort is that in your hands and forearms. The disc equipped version will have better power and modulation at the levers and depending on how much and how heavily you are braking this will lead to less fatigue in your gripping muscles.